# How to Retrieve the Primary Key When Saving a New Object in Anorm

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm using Scala Play! framework with Anorm to persist the data model to the database. I followed the example code [here](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku) :

```
case class Bar(id: Pk[Long], name: String)

object Bar {

  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
    get[String]("name") map {
      case id~name => Bar(id, name)
    }
  }

  def findAll(): Seq[Bar] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from bar").as(Bar.simple *)
    }
  }

  def create(bar: Bar): Unit = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("insert into bar(name) values ({name})").on(
        'name -> bar.name
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

}
```

Trying to expand on it, I want to retrieve the primary key just created and store it in the case class.

How can I retrieve the primary key?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `executeInsert` method instead of `executeUpdate`. Noted [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#anorm.Sql), the foremer method returns `Option[T]` where `T` is the type of the primary key.

You can extract the value with a `match` statement:

```
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        SQL(...).executeInsert()
    } match {
        case Some(long) => long // The Primary Key
        case None       => ...
    }
```

Comment: This only applies if the primary key is an auto increment key. If it not, the result will be None

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for `INSERT IGNORE` if there is no id inserted.

Comment: Or just `.executeInsert(scalar[Long] single)` without `match`