# Scala anorm retrieve inserted id

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm, typesafe-stack

I have a table with autoid for the id field. After inserting a row with anorm I'd like to retrieve the generated id. Any idea?

```
 SQL(
    """
      insert into accom (id,places,lat,lon,permaname,country,defaultLanguage) values (
         {places}, {lat}, {lon}, {permaname}, {country}, {defaultLanguage}
      )
    """).on(
      'id -> id,
      'places -> places,
      'lat -> lat,
      'lon -> lon,
      'permaname -> permaname,
      'country -> country,
      'defaultLanguage -> defaultLanguage).executeUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the latest version you need a scalar:

```
   val newId = SQL(
      """
      insert into accom (places,lat,lon,permaname,country,defaultLanguage) 
      values ({places}, {lat}, {lon}, {permaname}, {country}, {defaultLanguage})
      """).on(
        'places -> places,
        'lat -> lat,
        'lon -> lon,
        'permaname -> permaname,
        'country -> country,
        'defaultLanguage -> defaultLanguage).executeInsert(scalar[Long].single)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Without using the scalar parameter I was seeing strange column type mismatch errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use `executeInsert` instead of `executeUpdate`, and the return value is the id.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `executeInsert` method instead of `executeUpdate`; it returns an `Option[T]` where `T` is the type of the primary key.

You might want to take a look at [How to Retrieve the Primary Key When Saving a New Object in Anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859700/how-to-retrieve-the-primary-key-when-saving-a-new-object-in-anorm) which also shows you how to formulate your `INSERT` statement without specifying the id — which you want to have generated.